# OpenGL program immediately closes at runtime

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl

I'm running an OpenGL tutorial program using Visual Studio 10 and have seen it work on other machines but closes straight after running on mine. A small blank image display window pops up for a split second before it goes back to the code as if everything went smoothly.

Here is the output I'm getting:

```
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Tutorials\Debug\Tutorials.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\snxhk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Tutorials\Debug\glew32.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Nathan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Tutorials\Debug\freeglut.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\HsSrv.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dsound.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiglpxx.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atioglxx.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atiadlxy.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\propsys.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\userenv.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wtsapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IPHLPAPI.DLL', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winnsi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atigktxx.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\aticfx32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
'Tutorials.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atigktxx.dll'
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\atigktxx.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Tutorials.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xaf0) has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The program '[6208] Tutorials.exe: Native' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

I'm not great with this kind of stuff so hopefully someone here can make sense of this.

Comment: Output is kind-of useless here.  You need to step into the code and step through it.  I've got a feeling it's getting a bad return result from some function and exiting there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a look at the parameters being passed around in your functions as your log is reporting with:

**Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.**

First you should build it in Debug mode though, so that the PDB files will be generated and you can actually debug it.

**Project Properties - Configuration Properties - Linker - Debugging - Generate Debug Info : Yes**

Then just debug. As the comment mentions, the output is useless here, apart from the aforementioned line.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and I was probably running the same tutorial.

Use the debugger and find where the program crashes. If it's the function

```
static int FGAPIENTRY FGUNUSED glutCreateWindow_ATEXIT_HACK(const char *title) { return __glutCreateWindowWithExit(title, exit); }
```

Then your GPU might not be able to interpret this version of OpenGL.
Try updating the drivers, or find glutInitContextVersion(4,0) and give it the arguments for example `glutInitContextVersion(3,3)` for older version of OpenGL.